# Reading a float32 value from pymodbus gives incorrect value but modscan or ComTestPro

Tags: python, pymodbus

When reading a float32 value from pymodbus I always get an incorrect value but when same value is read from modscan or ComTestPro, it is read correctly every time.
This observation holds true for some registers only but for other registers pymodbus always reads the correct value with below code for float32 data only.

Using read holding register command to read the 2 register data, response data hex bytes reads 207 value instead of 500.

Expected value is :500, received value in response is :207

```py
readResult = client.read_input_registers(4621, 2, unit=1)
data = readResult.registers
value3 = struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('<HH', readResult.registers[0], readResult.registers[1]))[0]
y2 = round(np.float32(value3),2)
```

I also tried with below code:

```py
readResult = client.read_input_registers(4621, 2, unit=1)
data = readResult.registers
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(data, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little)
val = round((decoder.decode_32bit_float()), 2)
decoder.reset()
```

Observed the same log on wireshark for both pymodbus and comtestpro.
Response data is always correct for comtestpro for same register unlike on pymodbus.

Options I tried:
Changing byteorder and wordorder combinations.
Changing offset +1 and -1 for mentioned register while reading value from pyodbus, but it gives incorrect values for rest of the registers which
are being read with correct values.

Data received when read register 4621 from pymodbus library:

2020-06-24 10:20:15,900 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :120      Running transaction 2
2020-06-24 10:20:15,900 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :219      SEND: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0xe 0x3 0x12 0xd 0x0 0x2
2020-06-24 10:20:15,900 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2020-06-24 10:20:15,900 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :228      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2020-06-24 10:20:15,947 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :304      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2020-06-24 10:20:15,947 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :233      RECV: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0xe 0x3 0x4 0x5 0xbb 0x43 0x4f
2020-06-24 10:20:15,947 MainThread      DEBUG    socket_framer  :147      Processing: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0xe 0x3 0x4 0x5 0xbb 0x43 0x4f
2020-06-24 10:20:15,947 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :266      Factory Response[ReadHoldingRegistersResponse: 3]
2020-06-24 10:20:15,948 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :383      Adding transaction 2
2020-06-24 10:20:15,948 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :394      Getting transaction 2
2020-06-24 10:20:15,948 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :193      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
data y1  --> 207.02 [1467, 17231] , Raw hex value received in response: 0x5 0xbb 0x43 0x4f

Data received when read through Com test pro tool:

Response: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0xe 0x3 0x4 0x43 0xfa 0x16 0x8f
value: 500.176

Comment: I could solve the issue, it was related byteorder(Big was needed) and wordorder(Big was needed)endianess and offset(register address-1 was needed) setting. Thanks anyways!

Comment: same with this one:?https://community.teltonika.lt/t/modbus-decoding-problem/2250